# mvn jetty:run get a build failure

Tags: jetty, maven-3, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project and I ran it successfully with `mvn jetty:run` in the command window in windows. Then I tried **maven** build in **eclipse**. After that, it says that a build failure occurred and I end up with this kind of message after running `mvn jetty:run` in my command window.

```
Maven/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maven build in Eclipse you do not need to prepend `mvn` to your command.

Try using `jetty:run` instead of `mvn jetty:run`.

**Run As > Maven build > Goals : jetty:Run**

Answer (score 0):

Try the fully qualified plugin name eg `org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.22:run`

Comment: how can I use that plugin please can you explain.